# リカッチの代数方程式が解けない

Tags: python3, numpy, matlab

以下のコードを実行すると `ControlSlycot: can't find slycot module 'sb02md' or 'sb02nt'` というエラーが出ます。slycotをpipでインストールしようとしても`ERROR: Could not build wheels for slycot which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`というエラーが出ます。

controlでリカッチを解くことにはこだわっていませんので、方法があれば何でも教えてください。

```
from control.matlab import *
import  numpy as np
 
A = np.array([[0, 1],
            [0, -1]])
B = np.array([[0],
            [1]])
Q = np.array([[1, 0],
            [0, 1]])
R = np.array([[1]])

K, P, e = lqr(A, B, Q, R)
```

Comment: 参考までに、Ubuntu Linux 20.04, Python 3.8.5, pip 20.2.4 環境では slycot 0.4.0 のインストールは正常に行われて、`K, P, e = lqr(A, B, Q, R)` も実行できました。

Comment: [python-control/Slycot: Python wrapper for the Subroutine Library in Systems and Control Theory (SLICOT)](https://github.com/python-control/Slycot) を参照すると、**We publish Slycot to the Python package index, but only as a source package, so to install using pip you'll first need to install the build prerequisites (compilers, libraries, etc.)** と書かれていますので、pipでインストールする場合にはFortranコンパイラやBLAS/LAPACKが必要になります。また、**The easiest way to get started with Slycot is to install pre-compiled binaries from conda-forge (see below); ...** と書かれていますので、MinicondaかAnacondaを使う方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。正常に実行できたということは主さんはBLAS/LAPACKというようなものをインストールしていたということでしょうか

Comment: はい、こちらでは Ubuntu Linux を使っていて、必要なパッケージは全てインストール済でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/python-control/python-control/issues/90 にNumpyの問題とありますので、
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) からPythonのバージョンに合ったNumpy+mkl をDLして `pip install` すると私の環境Python 3.7.4 ではリカッチ計算できました。

Comment: そうでしたのね，ありがとうございます．助かりました